# Cartesian square root of a measure preserving action

Tags: gr.group-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $G \curvearrowright (X,\nu)$ be probability measure preserving action of a countable discrete group. When does there exist a probability measure preserving action $G \curvearrowright (Y,\mu)$ such that $G \curvearrowright (X,\nu)$ is isomorphic to the diagonal action $G \curvearrowright (Y \times Y, \mu \times \mu)$?

Comment: If the $X$ action is ergodic, then the $Y$ action must be weak-mixing and hence the $X$ action must be weak-mixing. (That is you cannot find a square root like this if the $X$ action is ergodic but not weak-mixing).

Comment: Thanks! For amenable groups (at least) it seems like it should be possible to take the square root of i.i.d. actions. I wonder if more can be said.

Comment: The terminology "square root" is slightly difficult because Ornstein used it to mean (for $\mathbb Z$ actions) a transformation $S$ such that $S^2=T$. For i.i.d., this seems straightforward as you say (just using entropy)

Comment: Thanks again Anthony. And yes - my choice of title is a little confusing.

Comment: Perhaps "Cartesian square root" would be a better terminology.

Comment: Could you please try to specify what do you mean by "when"? What kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: Ideally some kind of characterization would be good, or at least an interesting sufficient condition. But anything interesting would be interesting!   And at this point would suffice for being an acceptable answer.